# Limiting data transferred through a socket in c++

Tags: c++, sockets, compression, video-streaming, bandwidth

I am working on a USB redirection software which redirects USB device on network by adding a virtual USB device on client machine. Everything is working fine but client complains that when he connects a webcam with 640X480 resolution, the 100 Mbps network chokes. I have tested the webcam on 1 Gbps Adapter and it utilizes around 16% (160 Mbps) bandwidth. Should a webcam take this much bandwidth? Anyways he wants network usage to be under 50 Mbps.

I have tried compressing data which I get from DeviceIoControl and then decompressing it on client side before passing it to DeviceIoControl. Works fine for file transfer but video stops working and bandwidth goes down to around 50 Mbps. I have tried adding short delays before sending data but this also results in a black screen. Now I am thinking of somehow forcefully lowering the camera resolution to 320X240. I am not sure if there is any other way of decreasing data thrown by DeviceIoControl.

I would really appreciate if you could share your thoughts and lead me in right direction. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Its a YUV2 format webcam.

Is there any opensource library I can use to decrease frame rate or resolution of webcam on windows platform?

Comment: sounds like what you want to achieve is more in the lines of lowering the frame rate. then the resolution is less important, higher res, lower frame rate.

Comment: Is there a way to decrease the frame rate of a webcam? Which open source libraries can I use to interact with a webcam?

Answer (score 1):

If the data is uncompressed: 640 px/line × 480 lines/frame × 30 frames/sec × 24 bit/px ≈ 211 Mbps

You can check the documentation of the webcam whether it supports some sort of compression or frame rate control.

Comment: @umair: What is YUV2? Is that 12bpp? Then you have half that rate.

Comment: YUV2 is 16bpp which means uncompressed data is around 150 Mbps